# show hide multiple content with open/close text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the open close indicators (+/-) according to the open and close status of the menu link headers. When page loads, I can click one of the headers and all the links will close, but only the one indicator will change. I need all of the indicators to change according to each header link's actual status.

HERE IS MY EXTRACTED HTML

```
<h4 class="toggle">LINK ONE</h4>
<ul class="content">
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Users_All">Live tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Roles_DealerAdmin">Historical tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_SecurityGroups">Manage locations</a></li>
</ul>

<h4 class="toggle">LINK TWO</h4>
<ul class="content">
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Users_All">Live tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Roles_DealerAdmin">Historical tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_SecurityGroups">Manage locations</a></li>
</ul>

<h4 class="toggle">LINK THREE</h4>
<ul class="content">
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Users_All">Live tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Roles_DealerAdmin">Historical tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_SecurityGroups">Manage locations</a></li>
</ul>

<h4 class="toggle">LINK FOUR</h4>
<ul class="content">
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Users_All">Live tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Roles_DealerAdmin">Historical tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_SecurityGroups">Manage locations</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
    var target = $(this).next('.content');
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    target.slideToggle();
    $('.content').not( target ).slideUp();
});
```

HERE IS THE MY FIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/w59by22h/

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: use `.each()`;  try it

Comment: jQuery UI accordion does this: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the toggle indicator to change when you slide up all other content sections just remove the "expanded" class at the same time you slide them up.

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
    var target = $(this).next('.content');
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    target.slideToggle();
    $('.toggle').not( $(this) ).removeClass("expanded");
    $('.content').not( target ).slideUp();
});
```

If you want them to match when the page loads you have 2 options.

Option 1: If you want them to all start closed Make each UL tag have a style with display: none.

```
<h4 class="toggle">LINK ONE</h4>
<ul class="content" style="display: none;">
    <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Users_All">Live tracking</a></li>
    <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Roles_DealerAdmin">Historical tracking</a></li>
    <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_SecurityGroups">Manage locations</a></li>
</ul>
```

Option 2: If you want them to all start open add the "expanded" class to each h4

```
<h4 class="toggle expanded">LINK ONE</h4>
<ul class="content">
    <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Users_All">Live tracking</a></li>
    <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_Roles_DealerAdmin">Historical tracking</a></li>
    <li><a href="index_ct.html#/UserAdmin_SecurityGroups">Manage locations</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have also updated your fiddle to have them start closed.

https://jsfiddle.net/w59by22h/3/

Answer (score 1):

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/w59by22h/1/

```
    $(".toggle").each(
        function(i, el) {
             $(el).on("click", function(e){
                var target = $(this).next('.content');
                $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
                target.slideToggle();
                $('.content').not( target ).slideUp();
        });
        }
    );
```

attach .click event to each of .toggle class, instead all together

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
    $('.content').slideUp();
    $('.toggle').removeClass('expanded');

    var target = $(this).next('.content');
    if ( !target.is(':visible') ){
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        target.slideToggle();
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/w59by22h/4/)</kbd>